# Virtual server ImportError: No module named fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, import, amazon-ec2

Running an ec2 instance on aws; when attempting to run a script that imports several packages, all packages import correctly except one: 'fuzzywuzzy' (used for fuzzy string matching). I tried installing fuzzywuzzy from source code within the virtual server but aws reacted by auto-uninstalling it.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-215 BearTrap]$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:18:03) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> import string
>>> import ast
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> import fuzzywuzzy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fuzzywuzzy
```

Comment: did you try just doing `pip install fuzzywuzzy` thats how i installed it (although not on AWS)

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, aws didn't like that either

Comment: What about trying to install as root?

Comment: @wilbur maybe, but I'm more interested in why the environment can't see fuzzywuzzy

Comment: It's also possible that it's being installed in a location _not_ in your PYTHONPATH. Have you checked that?

Comment: *What exact commands* did you use to install the package?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa initially I simply tried running a script that had from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz. Then tried pip install fuzzywuzzy